# Doctrine 2 extreme optimization

Tags: php, performance, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I'm currently building a web application using Zend framework 1.11.11 and Doctrine 2.2. I searched a lot for the best ways and hacks to optimize the frameworks used.

During my search for Zend framework optimization I stumbled upon this post:
[Optimising the Zend Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4708754/optimising-the-zend-framework)

What was interesting about it is that it mentioned few optimization techniques that emerged from the usage of the framework itself and wasn't covered in the manual itself such as:

- disable viewRenderer and take care of view rendering yourself.

Now I'm looking for similar techniques that could be applied to Doctrine 2 other than the ones mentioned [here in the manual](http://readthedocs.org/docs/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/improving-performance.html).

**Note**

I know many will mention profiling the queries, caching and finding the bottle neck of the app, but that's not um looking for :) I am looking for practical enhancements discovered during Doctrine 2 usage.

Thanks ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, optimizing and hacking Doctrine 2 will not be an easy task. I can only advise you to follow the official "best practice":

- Use Query Cache
- Use Metadata Cache
- Pre-generate proxies
- Avoid listeners (or merge them by event type (flush, update), it will avoid the lookup time and the loop for subscribed events)
- Use lazy-loading whenever it is possible
- Make sure your relationships or inheritance are not messed up

(Note that I didn't mentioned Result cache which should **not** be a way to optimize an application)

From my use, the most important part I had to optimize was not Doctrine itself (while there are optimizations to do to the core) but the generated Query, as always, I `EXPLAIN`ed the queries and optimized indexes.

Doctrine 2 can be high memory consuming so loading a lot of entities at once may slow down your application, you may find it useful to known about `clear()`, `detach()`, `iterate()` methods.

Despite the fact Doctrine 2 can sometimes be slow, I mostly noticed that I was able to optimize application somewhere else, within the Zend Framework or PHP themselves.

Let's say, Doctrine 2 takes 100ms where Zend Framework takes 300ms for a total of 450ms (I/O stuffs, PHP internal functions, etc..)

If you can divide easily by two the time taken by Zend Framework, optimizing Doctrine 2 to gain like 10% will not increase notably the speed of your application. Think about it twice.

Here are a few tips:

- Create your own view instead of using View Helpers (avoid the helper lookup)
- Cache your Zend_Config object (really heavy load)
- Avoid Regex routes whenever possible (ZF routes are a big bottleneck)
- Use a ClassMap autoloader instead of the native Zend_Loader_Autoloader

There are tons of optimization to do, some have a real impact while others don't.

Make sure to find them by profiling your application, an easy and cross-platform is to use [webgrind](http://code.google.com/p/webgrind/).

Comment: +1 Thanks for the detailed answer, but could you please explain more about this point _Avoid Regex routes whenever possible (ZF routes are a big bottleneck)_? Actually I had a post a while ago that was asking about the same thing. Maybe you can provide an answer to it [Optimizing Zend framework routes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10070634/optimizing-zend-framework-routes)

Comment: Since this answer is very old, **hint:** make sure to upgrade to Zend Framework 2, which has been rewritten from ground up and is much faster in most scenarios.